# Job offer,but just started my new job

Tags: professionalism, new-job, job-change, ethics, careers

I recently accepted a position simply because I needed the money.

Previously I had applied to another position but they took a month to get back to me, which they finally did today: my first day at my new job.

This new position helps me in the long run for my career.

How do I tell my new employer that I am about to accept another offer that benefits me in terms of commute, pay and long term career wise?

Comment: No easy way to do it, I'm afraid.  Just be direct as in the answer by @AndreiROM and with luck there won't be a great deal of fallout.  I would suggest not putting this one on your CV in future though!

Comment: "*How do I tell my new employer?*" However you like, that's the equivalent of burning a bridge and then nuking it from orbit afterwards, just to be sure. If the first company is outside your field you might be able to pull this off without it impacting your reputation but doing this can come back to haunt you in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 9):

I think I've given this advice in about 3 questions in the past day:

> **Always keep your own priorities and goals in mind.**

This new job is the one that's going to *really* get you on the path to accomplishing yourself. There is no question that you must accept.

You are, most certainly, screwing your new boss over, but always keep in mind that any business will promote their interests first and foremost - even if it detrimental to you!

You'll have to be as polite as possible about it, but refusing the offer you've been dreaming about should be out of the question. Simply tell your boss the truth:

> I'm very sorry to put you in this situation, and I really appreciate the opportunity you gave me here, but I have just received a job offer from a company that is much closer to home, and is simply a better long term opportunity for me. I sincerely apologize for this, but I am going to accept their offer.

I would recommend leaving immediately, after all, you barely got through a single work day there. How would you give two weeks notice when you don't yet do anything there?

Good luck, and remember: always look out for number one - yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, honestly this really helped, you do this though that leaving immediately would be the best option?

Comment: Yup. You've been there a day - best to get it over with like ripping off a band-aid: fast. You don't know enough about the job to do anything useful for the next 2 weeks, and frankly why would the employer want to pay you when you are leaving right away? I wouldn't recommend this if you had been there for a few months, but as it stands, just apologize, say that you appreciate their kindness, and get out.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much honestly. This is what I needed to help me. Thumbs up.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Wait a little longer and see what other people have to say, but don't forget to come back and select an answer!

Comment: Did you actually get a CONTRACT to sign by this other company?  Or "did they get back to you" verbally but there is nothing to sign?  There is a big difference.